# How to count number of blocks needed to be read

Tags: function, pointers, operating-system

I have an examination paper of Operating System Concepts which contains a rather hard problem and I have to review it before taking exam. I don't quite understand about the problem and don't know how to count the number of blocks of a file referred on the problem. Please help me.

An operating system uses 32-bit pointer to allocate files with linked list method. Assume a block of data has the size of 4KB and the first 32 bits of the block contains the pointer, the rest contains the data. We also assume that the following function has been successfully called in an application program:

```
fd = open('myfile.bin',O_RDONLY);
```

and myfile.bin is a file having the size of 20480 bytes.

a) Count the number of blocks that needs to be read (including the block that contains the pointer to the first block of the list) when we perform the following system function

```
lseek(fd,16385,SEEK_SET); read(fd,&c,1);
```

b) Count the number of blocks that needs to be read when we have to continue performing the following system function right after the system function performance in part a.

```
lseek(fd,2048,SEEK_CUR); read(fd,&c,1);
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? Is it on the part that requires you turn the above sentences into mathematical formula?

Comment: I'm stuck in this part: (including the block that contains the pointer to the first block of the list). I don't understand this since the block has the size of 4KB and the pointer has the size of 32 bits?

Comment: Ahhhhhh! I thought that might be it.. If I may.. It seems to me that the point of the question is to confuse people and ensure they've accounted for everything. The key, I think, is that while each block is 4k in size, it actually holds 4 bytes less than 4k, since the first 32 bits are used for house-keeping.. So..... The most simple form of the first part is "How many blocks I have to read to get access to byte 4095 in the file?" The answer is of course, 2. Since it *should* be the last byte in the block, it would be 1 block access. Housekeeping (32 bits) makes us need the next. Helpful?

Comment: But I want to ask that the function lseek(fd,16385,SEEK_SET); will push the pointer to position 16385 or 20480 + 16385?

Comment: Position 16385... Though, I think you're being tricked. The size of the file isn't relevant for the two questions you've posed. (They might ask how many blocks the file needs in part c if it exists) Remember the question I imagined earlier, where I specified the last byte in a 4096 byte block? I think they're just doing the same thing - they want access to the last byte in the fourth block. Well, it *would* be the fourth block if you didn't have to use 4 bytes of each of them for house-keeping. ;)

Comment: So you mean the information about file size is redundant? Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: Yep. Seems like a (well chosen) red-herring.

Comment: Thanks. Can you verify the answers? The number of blocks in part a is 2? And the number of blocks in part b is 1?

Comment: Pleasure. Haven't seen the course material, so I could be overlooking something, For part a, I'd give the answer of 5. Byte at index 16385 should belong to the fourth block. But, you have 4 blocks * 32bits of house-keeping data. That means what would have been the last byte of the fourth block, is actually somewhere in the 5th. Here's an image  - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z17eQ.png - the red parts represent the part of the block that you cant use. The numbers are the index of the first or last byte in a region. Notice the last number? Remember my comment about a possible part C?

Comment: Forgive me for referring the size of file here. But I thought after the function fd = open('myfile.bin',O_RDONLY) being successfully called, the pointer was at 20480 and then the part a ask us to count the number of blocks when the pointer moves from 20480 to 16385? Hence, as what you said in previous comments, it should be 2 blocks?

Comment: Ahhhhr. Couldn't work out where we differed. Here's a man page of sorts for `open`. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/open.html - The relevant part being the sentence "The file offset used to mark the current position within the file shall be set to the beginning of the file." - I.e - you have to move forward from 0 to get to 16385, rather than backwards from 20480.

Comment: Oh! I get it. Thank you very much. A little more. Can you give the answer for the part b? I just want to verify the solution.

Comment: It looks like you have to seek forwards by 1/2 a block. If you failed to account for the missing 32bit sections, you'd reckon you had to seek forwards 1/2 a block from the last byte in a block. So, you'd need to read in 1. Thing is though, you're right at the start of the 5th block when you're at byte 16385. To advance forwards 1/2 a block from there, you'd just reposition the pointer in the data you've *already read*. My answer for this question would be 0.